# Does SSL non wildcard certificate work on sub folders/directories?

Tags: ssl, subdomain

If I were to get a single certificate and not a wildcard,
I know it wouldn't work for say, sub.example.com, but would it work for example.com/sub?

Because the wildcards are quite spendy, and I would like to find out my options. Because example.com/sub wouldn't be a sub domain would it? it would just be a folder/directory and therefore it should be covered by the SSL certificate since it's on the same domain or am I wrong?

I looked online, and it just mentioned subdomains or other domains, it said nothing about directories or folders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildcard certificates are used to secure multiple subdomains (eg. a.mydomain.com, b.mydomain.com etc).

As for folders - your certificate issued for www.mydomain.com will work fine for www.mydomain.com/some/folder/

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely cheaper than buying a wildcard, since I don't have sub domains. cheers.